# Test Class code coverage ( only couple of lines )

Tags: apex, code-coverage, class

Hello this is the first time i try to write a test class, but i don't understand exactly how i can test if the flow was actually launched.
Can someone help me with the test class ? It's only a couple of lines

```
global class ScheduledContractSend Implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        Map<String, Object> Params = new Map<String, Object>();
        Params.put('recordId','006p000000Aal2EAAR');
        Flow.Interview.testcontract flow1 = new 
        Flow.Interview.testcontract(Params);         
        flow1.start();}}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTestprivate class TestScheduledContractSend {
static testMethod void validateScheduledContractSend() {
    }}
```

Comment: Assuming this is a Record-Triggered Flow and has DML operations configured within the Flow setup, how about using [System.assert()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assert) to confirm the database changes as a result of the Flow? Or are you explicitly looking to test if the Flow interview alone was started? Keep in mind [startTest & stopTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm) for this.

Comment: Yes i just need to see if the flow started ( currently the code coverage is ofc 0% ).
In the flow i just have 2 dml operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test class worked for me.

```
private class ScheduledContractSendTest{
    @isTest
    private static void executeTest(){
        Test.startTest();
        ScheduledContractSend obj = new ScheduledContractSend();
        obj.execute(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not test that the flow was launched as there are no asserts that the flow's DML ever occurred. Imagine that someone had commented out the `flow1.start()` line, the above test would still pass.  Another approach is for the flow to pass back an output variable of `isSuccess` that he schedulable's `execute()` logs in an queryable `Log__c` object